# VSTO in Powerpoint: Changing custom task pane visibility in WindowSelectionChange moves selected shape

Tags: events, ms-office, vsto, powerpoint

I think I have found a bug.
I am developing a add-in for Powerpoint 2010. The event WindowSelectionChange is fired when a shape (e.g. a picture) is selected/deselected.
However, if I use this event to change the Visibility property of a Custom Task Pane, then the shape moves left/right on the slide. Example:

```
Private Sub Application_WindowSelectionChange(Sel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Selection) Handles Application.WindowSelectionChange
    cTaskPane.Visible = Not cTaskPane.Visible
End Sub
```

I have tried to monitor the Left property of the shape, and that does not change from the beginning to the end of the WindowSelectionChange sub. Thus, it must happen afterwards.

How can I avoid this?
Any workaround?

Comment: Also, I am not sure what fires after this event.

Comment: Please see a screen recording of the problem here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dr5Dy5mwOI0

Comment: Try to fire an event from the WindowSelectionChange and use the event callback to set the taskpane...

Answer (score 0):

It's because your mouse is holding the shape, and the shape gets moved to the right when the window is shrunk.

In more detail, the moving occurs in 4 steps:

1. You press mouse, caused window selection change, then the pane becomes visible, which makes the slide view window shrink;
2. Since the slide view window shrunk while your mouse's position remains to be the same, your mouse is moved right w.r.t the slide;
3. Since your mouse is pressing, the shape is anchored with your mouse, thus move to the current position of the mouse;
4. When pane becomes invisible again, the slide view window changes its size back, the shape is moving accordingly again.

To avoid this, I suggest you use WindowSelectionChange event and check if the selection is shape (code is in c#):

```
private void WindowSelectionChangedHandler(PowerPoint.Selection selection)
{
    if (selection.Type == PowerPoint.PpSelectionType.ppSelectionShapes)
    {
         //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, where are you getting this event from? It doesn't exist in VS2013 for either C# or VB. Where are you wiring it?

Comment: It should be WindowSelectionChange event. The handler's name is misleading, sorry about that :P I've updated the answer :)